# What does the following tag mean in HTML?

Tags: html

I have started to do a web project for school. I have made use of a template which has the following tag quite often: `<div class="col-lg-12">`.

What is the meaning and the use of it?

Comment: Your question is too broad and should be closed as off topic. Please read [ask] before posting

Comment: See: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the Bootstrap library.

The `<div>` tag indicates the opening of a generic block-level element.

The `class` attribute indicates that this element belongs to a named grouping. Here the classname given to it is "col-lg-12".

Classnames can be used either in css or JavaScript. In this case, it is used by CSS in the Bootstrap library.

Bootstrap defines the style for the `col-lg-12` classname as indicating that this div should take up the entire width of the screen on large screens. Bootstrap defines the entire screen to have a size of 12 columns. And this is saying that the div will take up all 12 columns on large devices.

Comment: Can you please explain how to divide a such column into rows?

Comment: @SanjeevieNissanka Can you explain a bit more what you mean? Can you not just add other divs inside of this div? i.e. `<div class="col-lg-12><div>row 1</div><div>row 2</div><div>row 3</div></div>`

Comment: The way you mentioned in the above comment (<div class="col-lg-12><div>row 1</div><div>row 2</div><div>row 3</div></div>) works very well.

Comment: @SanjeevieNissanka Great to hear. Last thing to mention, is that you do not need to use Bootstrap. If you are not linking to Bootstrap or have no need for it, just remove the `class="col-lg-12`.